# Oath2 redirect call is missing parameters

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I am trying to authenticate with a family history web service that authenticates using OAuth2. The basic workflow of the authentication is that I submit a get request against the web service requesting an authentication session. It returns in the body of the response HTML Code with some login components for user name and password. My PHP application then echoes the html code to the browser. The end user can then enter his or her user name and password, then submit to the web service. This is where the behavior becomes unclear. In theory, The web service should redirect to a predefined redirect URI with some parameters included in the URL. In practice, however, submitting the password redirects to the pre registered redirect URI, but there are no parameters included in the URL. My Project is written primarily in PHP. This is a snippit of the code that makes the inital request for an authentication session.

```
function logOn($mainURL, $credentials)
{
// create a new HTTP_Request object to be used in the login process
$request = new HTTP_Request();

// set the URL of the HTTP_Request object to the family search identity/login endpoint

$request->setUrl("https://web-service/authentication/path?response_type=code&client_id=".$credentials['key']."&redirect_uri=https://www.myredirectPage.edu/");

$request->_useBrackets = false;
$request->addHeader("User-Agent", $credentials['agent']);
$request->addHeader("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
$request->sendRequest();

//HTML_HEADER;

//the response will come in the form of an html file
$responseHtml = $request->getResponseBody();

//Dynamically load html from request body onto the browser to allow for authentication
echo $responseHtml;


return $credentials;
}
```

The end user will enter their login credentials using the loaded html components and hit submit. The web service then redirects to my redirect authentication page. The code there is provided below.

```
<?php

// process client request (Via url)
//gather code parameters from the redirect url.
if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
echo $_GET['code'];
}
else
{
echo "code not returned";
}
if (isset($_GET['error']))
{
echo $_GET['error'];
}
else
{
echo "error not returned";
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance to any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use Google Chrome's Network debugger tool, I saw that my project was making unexpected searches for Javascript and Css resources, all resulting in 404 (not found) errors. Upon closer inspection, I could see that the resources were relative paths to resources that are on the web service server. Rather than looking for 'https://webService.net/js/importantJavascript.js' (an existing file located on the service's web server), it was trying to find 'https://mywebpage.edu/js/importantJavascript.js'(a path to a file that doesn't exist).